# Visualisation of the Cantor set

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the first few iterations of the construction of the Cantor set. Since I am a TikZ beginner, I need your help. Thanks in advance.

More information about the Cantor set can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set. The idea is to successively remove middle-thirds.

Comment: I saw this, but was wondering if there isn't a simpler solution which is in some sense univeral.

Comment: Simpler than the 4 lines of code in the Tikz manual? I'm not sure what you mean by "in some sense universal".

Comment: Oh ok, didn't read the comments. I will have a look at it.